# Windows 7 Will Not Remember Remote Credentials

Tags: windows-7, credentials-manager

I am having that age-old problem of Windows 7 not remembering the credentials for a remote drive mapping.  I have tried both of the suggestions documented [here](https://www.majas-lapu-izstrade.lv/tutorial-force-windows-7-to-remember-credentials-for-mapped-network-drive-problem-solved/), but the issue persists - I am presented with a dialog requesting my password for the remote resource.

What else should I be checking?

Comment: Have you gone and removed the existing credentials and tried re-entering them?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that, does not make a difference.

Comment: So, removed the drive mapping in Explorer, then followed the guidance in [this](https://superuser.com/a/736738/298934) answer and it works. The server in question happens to be a samba server... would that have something to do with it? What is Windows doing differently between mapping a drive and store credentials in Explorer and Command Prompt?  The settings in the credential manager look identical to what they were previously.